# Ansible template giving error "Could not find or access template file "

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am building simple ansible script.
I am using template module.
My ansible playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: "{{ deployment_environment }}"
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars_files:
    - params.yml
  vars:
    artifactory_url: "url"
    artifact_name: "filebeat"
    release_url: "{{ artifactory_url }}/{{ artifact_name }}/{{ filebeat_version }}"
    logstash_url: "{{ logstash_url }}"
    log_path: "{{ logpath.split(',') }}"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        env_param: "{{ deployment_environment }}"

    
    - name: Download filebeat.j2 file from artifactory
      uri:
        url: "{{ release_url }}/filebeat.j2"
        method: GET
        validate_certs: no
        force_basic_auth: true
        return_content: no
        force: no
        user: "{{ arti_username }}"
        password: "{{ arti_pass }}"
        dest: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat"
        creates: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat/filebeat.j2"
        
   
    - name: Creates directory
      file:
        path: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat/templates"
        state: directory
   
    - name: Move filebeat.j2 file.
      copy: 
        remote_src: True 
        src: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat/filebeat.j2" 
        dest: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat/templates"
        mode: '0777'
    
    - name: create filebeat.yml file using template
      template:
        src: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat/templates/filebeat.j2" 
        dest: "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}/filebeat/filebeat-{{ filebeat_semver }}-linux-x86_64/filebeat.yml"
        mode: '0644'
```

When I am running this playbook, I am getting error:

```
TASK [create filebeat.yml file using template.] *********************************************** FAILED! =>
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Could not find or access '/repo/filebeat/templates/filebeat.j2' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"
}
```

I even tried using **remote_src: yes**, but its giving same error.
What can I do?

Comment: have you check if your file j2 is created on remote?

Comment: yes.. it is getting created..

Comment: the file j2 is the same for all remote servers? if not same are they a big files or not?

Comment: If they are not the same, using the word `template` is kind of abusive. I really don't see what prevents OP from putting that file on the controller. In the worst case scenario .(i.e. access to a single playbook file on the controller), you can write the content of the template in a variable inside the playbook and dump it to `/tmp/my-template.j2` with the`copy` module running on localhost prior to templating.

Answer (score 3):

The template file needs to exist on the controller, not on the target host. All templating happens on the Ansible controller, to avoid the security and performance issues that would arise from transferring all variable data to the targets.

Comment: Is there any way, I can bypass controller, and use target host, as i am not having access to controller.

Comment: `i am not having access to controller` <= then how do you push your playbook there and run it in that case?

Comment: For example, my ansible scripts are called from gitlab pipeline, which runs on gitlab runner. I dont have access to gitlab runner as it is shared.

Answer (score 1):

you cant access to the node manager, so the only solution i see is to render a template from variable with a customfilter, that depends how is the content of your file.j2

```
1) use module slurp to fetch the content of j2 file in memory of node manager
2) render the template with a customfilter (must know the content of your file.j2)
3) copy the result to the destination file
```

But there is a question, how you could create and launch playbook without to have access at node manager?